# Playing flash videos on my android app

Tags: android, flash

I have a webpage with flash embedded and when I play the video, I get Error loading media: File could not be played.

There should be a way possible because apps like viewster is able to play flash videos. Is there a way to bundle flash with my app and then play the videos?

Comment: did you use android webview kit to play this video?

Comment: Not sure about the kit,
I have used the standard webview code:

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        mWebView.loadUrl(url11);

Comment: webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

Comment: I have tried webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
Which is also deprecated.  setPluginsEnabled API is no longer available, I guess ?

Comment: check my solution again.

Answer (score 0):

Added this code in java code and android manifest.xml file

Jave code

webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

Simply add this to the tag under your Applications Manifest XML "Application Tag"

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: setPluginsEnabled was removed in API level 18, the alternate is setPluginState(which is also deprecated).

Comment: added it "android:hardwareAccelerated="true"" and check.

Comment: I am using webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

Also I have the android:hardwareAccelerated="true". I am still unable to play the flash video. 
Interestingly, Chrome browser is able to play it. Do I need to decrease the Target API level, any other ways ?

Comment: Update: I am able to play a few videos, which I was unable to earlier with hardwareAccelerated flag, yet a lot of them still doesn't play.